# I can't access updated values from livedata after recreating activty

Tags: android-fragments, kotlin, viewmodel, koin

I am sharing data between activity and fragments in my app. I am using for this sharedviewmodel feature of koin. Basically; when i log in, i am setting token value in mainactivty and accessing it successfully in fragments. After recreating activity, i am setting token but i am not able to access updated token value in fragments. I am getting old value.

I tried to remove observers in ondestroy method but it didnt help at all. I can't realize what the problem is.

Viewmodel class

```
class SharedViewModel : ViewModel() {

    var token = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun setToken(t: String) {
        token.value = t
    }

}
```

Activity class

```
private val sharedViewModel by viewModel<SharedViewModel>()

private fun getToken() {
    token = intent.getStringExtra("token")!!
    sharedViewModel.setToken(token)
}
```

Fragment class

```
private val sharedViewModel by sharedViewModel<SharedViewModel>()

sharedViewModel.token.observe(this, Observer { 
        
})
```

Thanks for your helping.

**Edit - Koin Definition**

```
val networkModule = module {
    ...
}

val viewModelModule = module {
    ...
    viewModel { SharedViewModel() }
}

val fragmentModule = module {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you add your koin module definition?

Answer (score 2):

I have just checked my own app and there is a case where I use a ViewModel in the Activity and its child fragments. I create it everywhere using `by sharedViewModel()`. In your case you create it using `by viewModel()` in the Activity. Maybe you could change to `by sharedViewModel()` that and see if it works?

Comment: I had the same problem, I solved by always getting viewModels with 'by sharedViewModel()'.

Answer (score 1):

There is too little information to be sure, however this is a possibility:

If you are accessing the old value in the Fragment, that means that you probably are referencing an old instance of the viewModel in the Fragment. ViewModels don't live forever, they will be destroyed with the Activity, unless the Activity is destroyed because of a configuration change and then immediately recreated. According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModel):

> A ViewModel is always created in association with a scope (an fragment or an activity) and will be retained as long as the scope is alive. E.g. if it is an Activity, until it is finished.
>
> In other words, this means that a ViewModel will not be destroyed if its owner is destroyed for a configuration change (e.g. rotation).

Why does your Fragment keep the reference to the old ViewModel? This would mean that the Fragment is not destroyed and recreated with the Activity, for example because you keep a reference to the Fragment or because the Fragment is used in another Activity.

The `by sharedViewModel()` will only pass the ViewModel once in the Lifecycle of the Fragment object, at the first access of the sharedViewModel property.

Comment: It makes sense but all my fragments are attached only to main activity.  I think they should be destroyed when activity finishes.

Comment: @Berkay Kirecci are you sure you do not keep a reference to the fragment in another place?

Comment: I am sure. I think it's about koin implementation, i just added a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. Somehow there is a problem with koin implementation but i couldn't figure it out.

I've changed viewmodel implementation like this:

Activity:

```
private lateinit var sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel
...
...
sharedViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
```

Fragment:

```
private lateinit var sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel
...
...
activity?.let {
        sharedViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(it).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
}
```

And it works.
Let me know if anybody figures out problem about koin imp., thanks.